# asp.net mvc: pass information between 2 controllers to the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

hope i can explain myself...
i have a login control in the masterpage. when you click the login button you go to the accountcontroller's logon method which checks your credentials. whether it is ok or not, you will be redirected to the homepage with a redirecttoaction("home","index").
but, in case login failed, i want to show a message to the user.
so what i tried was setting viewdata in the logon method (viewdata["logon"] = "failed") and then check in the masterpage if this viewdata was present and if  so, render a span with some text.
but as i understand the viewdata is not preserved with the redirect to action method.

what is the best way to make sure my logon method can somehow notify my masterpage view that login failed?

Michel

Comment: See this project to send FlashMessages in your application
http://maff.ailoo.net/2009/06/build-a-flashmessenger-system-in-aspnet-mvc/ I guess that can help you! []´s

Comment: Read too about TempData See:
http://www.persistall.com/archive/2007/12/22/asp.net-mvc-a-ha-moment-tempdata--flash.aspx []´s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read your question correctly your problem is that you need to set a value in your action that need to be available after RedirectToAction. You would need to set a key in Tempdata.

```
TempData["MessageToUser"] = "I dont let you in dude!"
```

TempData is still available after **one** redirect.

Comment: yep, that is correct. But tempdata is stored in session, isn't it?
the rest of the app works without sessionstate, and i don't think i'm allowed to introduce sessionstate for this one...

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib). [Queen3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119224/queen3) somewhere mentioned that they have cure for this
(passing information between redirects).

But it would be better to create separate view for authentication. Then problem would just disappear.

Comment: hmm, nice though. maybe an ajax form, then i have no postback AND a separate view.

Comment: hmm, makes sense, think i'll do a redirecttoaction on succes, and a return view("") on fail. in the latter case the viewdata will be preserved